Sitecore 10.4 SXA Website Appears Blank After Unicorn Sync in Higher Environment
We are working on a website built in Sitecore 10.4 using SXA. After performing a Unicorn sync on a higher environment (staging), the website appears blank, with no content being displayed. The synchronization included only website-related YAML files. We haven't made any recent code or configuration changes that would explain this behavior.

Could someone provide insights into why this might be happening? Are there any known issues with Unicorn sync in SXA or specific troubleshooting steps we should follow to resolve the blank page issue?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

did you checked the items are there on the staging database...Any error on the log files?
